# More Than One Implicits Being Picked Up

Tags: scala, playframework, implicit

How do I make my code choose one specific implicit when the compiler finds more than one:

```scala
ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both method writes in trait Implicits of type [A](implicit evidence$1: models.Foo[A])play.api.libs.json.Writes[A]
[error]  and method stringableWrites in trait LowPriorityWrites of type [T](implicit conv: T => String)play.api.libs.json.Writes[T]
```

Comment: You can try to import desirable implicit (`import com.example.foo`) or unimport undesirable (`import com.example.{foo => _, _}`) if the latter is not in implicit scope.

Comment: But there can be many reasons for ambiguity or divergence. For example some type is not inferred or some type mismatch. It's better to prepare minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I found out what it was - i imported this json lib  but the version was too advanced for the play version i am using - i dropped down a version and now there are no clashes on the implicits